MissingType: Element 'ProductEntity' references a type that is not present
I'm working on a Kotlin Multiplatform project and trying to integrate a Room database. I'm using KSP and I'm encountering the following error during compilation:
[ksp] [MissingType]: Element 'ProductEntity' references a type that is not present
I can't figure out which type it means
Code
Here is the relevant part of my code:
Database
       import androidx.room.BuiltInTypeConverters
       import androidx.room.ConstructedBy
       import androidx.room.Database
       import androidx.room.RoomDatabase
       import androidx.room.RoomDatabaseConstructor
       import androidx.room.TypeConverters
       import com.example.shopapp.converter.CategoryObjectConverter
       import com.example.shopapp.converter.ListConverter
       import com.example.shopapp.data.AppDatabase.Companion.VERSION
       import com.example.shopapp.data.local.dao.CartDao
       import com.example.shopapp.data.local.dao.ProductsDao
       import com.example.shopapp.data.local.entity.CartProductEntity
       import com.example.shopapp.data.local.entity.ProductEntity
       import com.example.shopapp.getAppDatabase
       
       @TypeConverters(
           CategoryObjectConverter::class ,
           ListConverter::class ,
           builtInTypeConverters = BuiltInTypeConverters()
       )
       @ConstructedBy(AppDatabaseProvider::class)
       @Database(
           version = VERSION,
           exportSchema = false,
           entities = [
               ProductEntity::class,
               CartProductEntity::class,
           ],
       )
       abstract class AppDatabase : RoomDatabase() {
       
           abstract fun getCartDao(): CartDao
       
           abstract fun getProductsDao(): ProductsDao
       
       
           companion object {
               const val VERSION = 1
               const val NAME = "my_room"
           }
       }

        class AppDatabaseProvider (): RoomDatabaseConstructor<AppDatabase>{

        override fun initialize(): AppDatabase  = getAppDatabase()

          }       

Entities
  package com.example.shopapp.data.local.entity

  import androidx.room.Entity
  import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
  import androidx.room.TypeConverters
  import com.example.shopapp.converter.CategoryObjectConverter
  import com.example.shopapp.converter.ListConverter
  import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
  
  @TypeConverters(CategoryObjectConverter::class , ListConverter::class)
  @Entity(tableName = "productEntity" )
  @Serializable
  data class ProductEntity(
      @PrimaryKey
      val id: Long,
      val title: String,
      val price: Double,
      val description: String,
      val category: Category,
      val images: List<String>,
  )
  
  @Entity(tableName = "cart" )
  @TypeConverters(CategoryObjectConverter::class , ListConverter::class)
  @Serializable
  data class CartProductEntity(
      @PrimaryKey
      val id: Long,
      val title: String,
      val price: Double,
      val description: String,
      val category: Category,
      val images: List<String>,
      val quantity: Int
  )
  
  data class CartProduct(
      val id: Long,
      val title: String,
      val price: Double,
      val description: String,
      val category: Category,
      val images: List<String> ,
      //val rating: Rating ,
      val quantity: Int
  )
  
  /*data class RatingEntity(
      val rate: Double,
      val count: Int
  )*/
  
  @Serializable
  data class Category(
      val id: Int,
      val name: String,
      val image: String )
  
  @Serializable
  data class Product(
      val id: Long,
      val title: String,
      val price: Double,
      val description: String,
      val category: Category,
      val images: List<String>
  )

versions:
 room = "2.7.0-alpha06"
 room_compiler = "2.7.0-alpha06"
  sqlite  = "2.5.0-SNAPSHOT"
  ksp = "2.0.0-1.0.21"

gradle :
    plugins {
        alias(libs.plugins.kotlinMultiplatform)
        alias(libs.plugins.androidApplication)
        alias(libs.plugins.buildConfig)
        alias(libs.plugins.kotlinx.serialization)
        alias(libs.plugins.compose.compiler)
        alias(libs.plugins.compose)
        alias(libs.plugins.room)
        alias(libs.plugins.ksp)
        id("com.google.osdetector") version "1.7.3"
    }
    
    kotlin {
        androidTarget {
            compilations.all {
                kotlinOptions {
                    jvmTarget = "1.8"
                }
            }
        }
        
        listOf(
            iosX64(),
            iosArm64(),
            iosSimulatorArm64()
        ).forEach {
            it.binaries.framework {
                baseName = "shared"
                isStatic = true
                // Required when using NativeSQLiteDriver
                linkerOpts.add("-lsqlite3")
            }
        }
    
    /*    linuxX64() {
            binaries {
                executable()
            }
        }*/
    
        sourceSets {
    
            androidMain.dependencies {
                implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
                implementation(libs.androidx.activity.compose)
                implementation(libs.compose.ui.tooling)
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.okhttp)
                implementation(libs.core)
                implementation(libs.core)
                implementation(libs.custom.ui)
                implementation(libs.koin.android)
                implementation(libs.koin.androidx.compose)
                implementation(libs.androidx.glance.app.widget)
                implementation(libs.androidx.glance.material3)
                implementation(libs.androidx.glance.app.widget)
                implementation(libs.androidx.glance.material3)
            }
    
            commonMain.dependencies {
                // Compose
                implementation(compose.runtime)
                implementation(compose.material3)
                implementation(libs.screen.size)
                implementation(compose.material)
                implementation(compose.animation)
    
                //Networking
                implementation(libs.ktor.core)
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.content.negotiation)
                implementation(libs.kotlinx.serialization.json)
                implementation(libs.kotlinx.datetime)
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.logging)
                implementation(libs.io.ktor.ktor.client.serialization)
                api(libs.koin.core)
                implementation(libs.koin.compose.viewmodel)
    
                implementation(libs.room.runtime)
                implementation(libs.sqlite.bundled)
    
                implementation(libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core)
                implementation(libs.gson)
    
                implementation(libs.kamel.image)
                @OptIn(org.jetbrains.compose.ExperimentalComposeLibrary::class)
                implementation(compose.components.resources)
            }
    
            iosMain.dependencies {
                implementation(libs.ktor.client.darwin)
    
            }
    
    
            commonTest.dependencies {
                implementation(libs.kotlin.test)
            }
    
        }
    
    }
    
    android {
        namespace = "com.example.shopapp"
        compileSdk = 34
    
        defaultConfig {
            minSdk = 24
        }
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
            targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        }
        buildFeatures {
            compose = true
        }
        composeOptions {
            kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.14"
        }
    }
    
    task("testClasses") {}
    
    
    room {
        schemaDirectory("$projectDir/schemas")
    }
    
    dependencies {
       /* add("kspCommonMainMetadata", project(":test-processor"))
        add("kspJvm", project(":test-processor"))
        add("kspJvmTest", project(":test-processor")) // Not doing anything because there's no test source set for JVM
        // There is no processing for the Linux x64 main source set, because kspLinuxX64 isn't specified
        add("kspLinuxX64Test", project(":test-processor"))*/
        ksp(libs.room.compiler)
    
    }
    




  


This method worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/79307696/13651898

ksp beta release does not support converters at this moment so try to remove
@TypeConverters(CategoryObjectConverter::class , ListConverter::class)

and if you are still getting same error and if you are using room on multiplatform then
kotlin = "2.0.20-RC"
room = "2.7.0-alpha01"
ksp = "2.0.20-RC-1.0.24"

and add ksp.useKSP2=true to your gradle.properties (if you are using kotlin 2.x.x)
this will fix your problem and if you still getting the same error then try to remove @TypeConverters(<converter class name>::class)
